# How can I format a date string coming from the backend?

Tags: javascript, date

I am using Reactjs and ES6 in the frontend. And GraphQL to make some API calls.
I am getting a key named `createDate` with a value like this:

`2017-03-29T07:19:05-07:00`

And I need to format it like this:

`03/29/2017 07:19 AM` it should show `AM` or `PM`.

As this is an string and I am not using any library, I expect someone could guide me to a solution...

Comment: There are [*many duplicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string). Please do some research, write some code and post what you've tried before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the String to a date object first

```
var d = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00-06:30");
```

Then define a function constructs the string you want to use for representing the date. For example

```
function dateToString(d) {
   var year = d.getFullYear();
   var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() returns 0-11
   .
   .
   .
   return year + "-" + month "-" + ...;


}
```

Comment: Using the built–in parser is not recommended due to quirks in various implementations, e.g. Safari incorrectly treats "2015-03-25T12:00:00" as UTC, not local.